# XML Parser. NumberFormatException на ровном месте

Tags: java, android, xmlparser

Есть метод, который получает элементы `xml.parsers`:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

private Currency getXMLCurrency(Node item, String date) {
    Currency currency = new Currency();
    if (item.getNodeType() == item.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element element = (Element) item;
        currency.setdCode(getTagValue("NumCode", element));
        currency.setCode(getTagValue("CharCode", element));
        currency.setForAmount(Integer.parseInt(getTagValue("Nominal", element)));
        currency.setRate(Double.parseDouble(getTagValue("Value", element).replace(",", ".")));
        currency.setDate(date);
    }
    return currency;
}
```

Элементы извлекаются в другом методе, который возвращает `String`:

```
private static String getTagValue(String tag, Element element) {
        NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
        Node node = (Node) nodeList.item(0);
        String s = node.getNodeValue();
        Log.d("VALUE", s);
        return s;
    }
```

Вот элемент обрабатываемой XML-страницы:

```
<Valute ID="R01010">
<NumCode>036</NumCode>
<CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Name>Австралийский доллар</Name>
<Value>16,0102</Value>
</Valute>
```

При попытке выполнить строчку:

```
        currency.setForAmount(Integer.parseInt(getTagValue("Nominal", element)));
```

выскакивает `NumberFormatException`. Выглядит это так:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "
                                                                                                1
                                                                                               "
                                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                                                 at com.xpendence.development.currencyconverter.operations.Strategy.getXMLCurrency(Strategy.java:122)
```

При том, что `Log.d` показывает:

```
04-29 05:52:16.824 13060-13115/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter D/VALUE:    1
```

— вполне себе обычную единицу.

Я уж не знаю, что делать. Прошу помощи.

Comment: попробуйте `currency.setForAmount(Integer.parseInt(getTagValue("Nominal", element).trim()));` возможно в значения попадают пробелы

Comment: Спасибо, помогло :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте

```
currency.setForAmount(Integer.parseInt(getTagValue("Nominal"‌​, element).trim()));
```

возможно в значения попадают пробелы